# How do I pass a script block and parameters with a space in them to a new PowerShell instance?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have looked at many different questions/answers on here and done some research, but I can't solve this problem. I am running a script to check registry entries, but I need to use Powershell 32-bit on a 64-bit machine. So I am running PowerShell in 32-bit mode and passing it my script block. I need the script block to be able to access the parameters, though, so I am passing them in with the script block as well. When I run my code, though, my first parameter ($RegistryKey) gets broken apart at the space with the variable. I have tried escaping the string several different way, but nothing is working. Hopefully somebody can help me.

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Powershell script to check registry entry (as first argument to script) and display output on stdout.
#
# Arguments:
#       $RegistryKey: The registry key.
#       $RegistryValue: The registry value name.
#           $Use32BitPowerShell: Boolean as string for whether to use 32-bit PowerShell
#
# Returns:
#       If the registry key exists, and the registry value name is valid, return the registry key,
#           registry value name, registry data, and exists as true
#       If the registry key exists, and the registry value name is invalid, return only the registry 
#       key and exists as false
#       If the registry key doesn't exist, return exists property as false
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$RegistryKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SOME NAME\"
$RegistryValue = 'ValueName_String_StringValueMixedCase'
$Use32BitPowerShell = 'TRUE'

$script =
{
    param([string]$RegistryKey, [string]$RegistryValue, [string]$Use32BitPowerShell)

    # Initialize the RegistryEntry object to be returned.
    $result = New-Object PSObject | select Key, ValueName, DataType, Data, KeyExists, ValueExists, CorrectDataType, CorrectData
    $result.Key = $RegistryKey
    $result.ValueName = $RegistryValue
    $result.DataType = ''
    $result.Data = ''
    $result.KeyExists = $false
    $result.ValueExists = $false
    $result.CorrectDataType = $false
    $result.CorrectData = $false

    # Create a path for the key in the registry.
    $regentry = 'Registry::' + $RegistryKey
    $regentry

    # Get the key object for the registry entry path.
    $key = Get-Item -LiteralPath $regentry

    # If the key exists, get the data for the parameter registry value name. 
    # Set the KeyExists flag on the result object to true.
    if ($key)
    {
        # The key exists, so set the KeyExists flag on the result object to true.
        $result.KeyExists = $true

        # Get the data for the value.
        $data = $key.GetValue($RegistryValue)

        # If there is data, add the data to the result object.
        if ($data)
        {
            # The value exists, so set the ValueExists flag on the result object to true.
            $result.ValueExists = $true

            # Set RegistryData on the result object to the value data.
            $result.Data = [String]$data

            # Set DataType on the result object to the value data type.
            $result.DataType = $key.GetValueKind($RegistryValue)
        }
    }

    # Return a RegistryEntry object.
    # return $result
    $result
}

if ($Use32BitPowerShell.ToUpper() -eq 'TRUE')
{
    & "$env:WINDIR\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -command "& {$script} -argumentlist $RegistryKey $RegistryValue $Use32BitPowerShell"
}
```

Comment: Or just use the 64 bit registry key that points to the 32 bits registry: $RegistryKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\SOME NAME\"

Comment: I know that Windows does the mapping of registry keys to the WOW6432Node directory, but my goal is not to manipulate the input registry key. I'd like to just look it up.

Answer (score 1):

To test your script I have modified the script to test just the spacing issue.

Try this

```
$RegistryKey = "'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SOME NAME\'"
$RegistryValue = 'ValueName_String StringValueMixedCase'
$Use32BitPowerShell = 'TRUE'
$script =
{
    param(
    [string]$RegistryKey, 
    [string]$RegistryValue,
    [string]$Use32BitPowerShell
    )   
     Write-host $RegistryKey, $RegistryValue, $Use32BitPowerShell
}
if ($Use32BitPowerShell.ToUpper() -eq 'TRUE')
{
    & "powershell.exe" -NoProfile -command "& {$script} -argumentlist '$RegistryKey' '$RegistryValue' '$Use32BitPowerShell'"
}
```

And then run the script -I have named the script as spaces.ps1

```
PS C:\scripts\so> .\spaces.ps1
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SOME NAME\ ValueName_String StringValueMixedCase
```